# How to add rows to UITableView when paginating?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to append my UITableView with more rows once the user reaches the bottom of UITableView. However, once I try to scroll to the bottom to call more data I get an error that says:

```
 fatal error: Index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if !isLoadingMore && (maximumOffset - contentOffset <= threshold) {
        self.isLoadingMore = true

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.fetchMovieData()
            self.isLoadingMore = false
        }
    }
}
```

I am also keeping track of how many rows are being added to my table view adding to my rowNumber count as more data is called:

```
var rowNumber: Int = 0
```

Here is where I am making my request:

```
func fetchMovieData(_ url: String,_ params: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        if more {
            Alamofire.request(url, parameters: params)
                .responseJSON {
                    response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        self.currentPageNumber += 1
                        let json = JSON(value)
                        self.movieObject = [MovieModel.init(data: json)]
                        self.rowNumber += self.movieObject[0].movieList[0].movieDict.count
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I guess my question is should I be calling:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

In order to append my table view with more data or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Well, this should do it. It seems that your problem lies here : `self.movieObject = ...` - you create new model, replacingg the old one. You should construct your model object, so that you can append new data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not appending your array with more data instead you are replacing the old data with the new one which will keep the array count 10 for example, but the row count will increase, so the index out of range error will occur because you are trying to access array[11] for example but you have only 10 elements in that array.

To solve this try to replace your function with this:

```
 func fetchMovieData(_ url: String,_ params: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    if more {
        Alamofire.request(url, parameters: params)
            .responseJSON {
                response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    self.currentPageNumber += 1
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let newArray = [MovieModel.init(data: json)]
                    for i in newArray {
                   self.movieObject.append(i)
                  }
                    self.movieObject = [MovieModel.init(data: json)]
                    self.rowNumber += self.movieObject[0].movieList[0].movieDict.count
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly right. I had to adjust the logic some, but this was the right answer. Thank you!